# webpack compile incorrect ES version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I have a problem with React webb application on IOS 16.3 and lower version.
I discovered that my compile crete static class methods that not supported in ES5, that course syntax problems (SyntaxError: Unexpected token { )

The problem is that i need to  webpack + babel + tsconfig. (I used nx before and hasnt such problem with project src code)

webpack.config.js

```
{
   test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   use: ["babel-loader"],
}
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  "babelrcRoots": ["*"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators"
  ],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": "> 2.5%, not dead",
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "forceAllTransforms": true,
        "corejs": 3,
        "debug": true
      }
    ],

    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "es5", "es2015.promise"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "images.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["public", "node_modules"]
}
```

I tried a lot of files combination but, still see non ES5 syntaxis in compiled file

Why target in ts config do not work correctly